# List of values in latex

Tags: latex

I am updating documentation written in latex, and I have to implement kind of box which will contain list of possible values and default value for specified item.

Tex files already contain some predefined constructions.

There is an entry, defined by **\newcommand**, which takes input parameters and creates a box.
It is used in next way:

```
%Input values {Min & Max & Default}:    
{0 & 1 & 0}
```

In final pdf file this construction transforms to next representation:
[image]

As I understood it is implemented in next piece of code:

```
\makebox[\linewidth][r]{
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
    Input values: & \mitalic{Min} & \mitalic{Max} & \mitalic{Default} \\ & #8 \\
    & & & \\
    \end{tabular}
}
```

My goal is to implement something similar with next result:

[image]

Here number of possible values can be different.

I have not had any experience with latex before, so sorry if for some of you it is stupid question.

**UPDATE (19.08.2015):**

I have used next construction to achieve my goals (see answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254303/how-to-define-a-command-that-takes-more-than-18-arguments) for more information):

```
\newcommand{\ParseOptMenuItemList}[1]
{
\def\tmplist{#1}%
\@tempcnta=\z@
\@for\tmp:=\tmplist\do{\advance\@tempcnta\@ne
\expandafter\let\csname temp\@roman\@tempcnta\endcsname\tmp
}%
\makebox[\linewidth][r]{%
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        Possible values: \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempi}{}}{}{& \tempi\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempii}{}}{}{& \tempii\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempiii}{}}{}{& \tempiii\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempiv}{}}{}{& \tempiv\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempv}{}}{}{& \tempv\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempvi}{}}{}{& \tempvi\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempvii}{}}{}{& \tempvii\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempviii}{}}{}{& \tempviii\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempix}{}}{}{& \tempix\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempx}{}}{}{& \tempx\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempxi}{}}{}{& \tempxi\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempxii}{}}{}{& \tempxii\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempxiii}{}}{}{& \tempxiii\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempxiv}{}}{}{& \tempxiv\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempxv}{}}{}{& \tempxv\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempxvi}{}}{}{& \tempxvi\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempxvii}{}}{}{& \tempxvii\\}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\tempxviii}{}}{}{& \tempxviii\\}
      Default value: & \tempxix\\
    \end{tabular}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to compile the following minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\inputvals}[5]{%
  \makebox[\linewidth][r]{%
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
      Possible values: & #1\\
       & #2\\
       & #3\\
       & #4\\[.7em]
      Default value: & #5\\
    \end{tabular}
}}

\begin{document}

\inputvals{x}{y}{z}{t}{u}

\end{document}
```

This should give something very similar to what you ask. Notice that a command `\inputvals` is defined in the *preamble* (before `\begin{document}`) by using `\newcommand`, and then `\inputvals` is used in the document specifying its 5 arguments. Let us know if this implementation fits your requirements.